# In CSS how to set a different z-index property for two elements of the same class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just don't come up with an idea how to do the following:
In my html-document i have two elements of the class "modal" (the bootstrap modal class).
The one modal must have a z-index of -5 and the other 10.
How could I achieve this?I suppose that I could use IDs,but I have no idea how exactly to write the code...
Thank you !

Comment: Why you need a negative z-index, having 32 bits of possibilities? If you add 5 to your z-index you'll obtain `0` and `15`. By this way you don't need to have negative z-index that will throw your boxes just above the background layer stack. Take care with negative z-index if you don't understand to where the boxes will go.

Comment: I don't think that you understood my question. I have an element :
<div class="modal" .......... </div>
I also have another element 
<div class="modal" .......... </div>

How to make both elements with a different z-index?

Comment: I understand your question. You'll achieve that using different attributes like `id` or any custom `data-*` attribute (for example: `<div class="modal" id="lowerIndex">` and `<div class="modal" id="upperIndex">`. What I tell you about negative z-index was only a suggestion, but a real useful suggestion, because using negative z-index for this purposes are wrong and invalid! Negative z-index will be thrown your elements to rooms that you don't expect!

Answer (score 0):

Posting some code would be nice that way you can get a direct answer.

but yes use id's

```
    <div class="theexampleclass">
        <div id="example"></div>
        <div id="example2"></div>
</div>
```

in css

```
    #example {
     z-index: -5;
    }
    #example2 {
     z-index: 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very straight forward. Just focus on Z-index properties as other properties are applied to enhance look and feel.

See below working example:

```css
/*--CSS--*/
 div {
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    #a {
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       z-index: 1;
       background: rgba(255,0,0,0.75);
    }
    
    #b {
       top: -25px;
       left: 25px;
       z-index: 2;
       background: rgba(0,255,0,0.75);
    }
    
    #c {
       top: -50px;
       left: 50px;
       z-index: 3;
       background: rgba(0,0,255,0.75);
    }
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
 <div id="a"> A </div>
    <div id="b"> B </div>
    <div id="c"> C </div>
```

Demo Fiddle 1 : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/LLepva6L/

Demo Fiddle 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/8yyn6qcq/

Answer (score 0):

```css
 div {
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin:5px auto;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .fst {
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       z-index: 1;
       background: rgba(0,120,0,0.75);
      color:gold;
    }

    .snd {
       bottom: 15px;
       left: 50px;
       z-index: 2;
       background: rgba(0,0,190,0.75);
      color:gold;
    }

    .trd {
       bottom: 30px;
       left: 0;
       z-index: 3;
       background: rgba(255,0,0,0.75);
      color:gold;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="fst"> 1st Div </div>
    <div class="snd"> 2nd Div </div>
    <div class="trd"> 3rd Div  </div>
```